# Kubernetes Secrets as environment variables not working

Tags: java, kubernetes, deployment, environment-variables, quarkus

I have the following kubernetes secret:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: <name>
type: Opaque
data:
  DB_USER: 
  DB_PASS: 
  DB_NAME: 
  MQTT_CONNECTOR: 
  MQTT_HOST: 
  MQTT_PORT: 
  MQTT_TOPIC: 
  MQTT_USERNAME: 
  MQTT_PASSWORD:
```

I have ensured that the base64 encoding of the variables was done correctly. All values show up in the k8s dashboard under the secrets tab correctly.
I am loading the secret variables as environment variables

```
envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: <name>
```

When logging the environment variables in the pod itself, most of the variables are logged correctly. However `DB_USER`, `MQTT_CONNECTOR` and `MQTT_USERNAME` are not logged.

Before i added all the 'mqtt' variables, all 3 'db' were loaded and logged correctly. The database connection was working as expected. However after adding the 'mqtt' variables, `DB_USER` was not logged any more.
It seems like there are somehow too much environment variables and it just skips some randomly.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the syntax. Please ensure the following

1. secret and pod are in same namespace
2. kubectl get secret <name> -o yaml and check if any syntax error in data yaml

Comment: Secret and Pod are in the same namespace, most of the environment variables get displayed when logging them in the pod. DB_USER MQTT_CONNECTOR and MQTT_USERNAME for some reason not.